# How to avoid phantom reads in hibernate

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate, transactions

In a spring-hibernate application, It has a business transaction which insert appointments to database and finally it will return an appointment number back to the user.

```
@Transactional
public int makeAppointment(Appointment a) {

 step 1: read current appointments count (current appointments list size)
 step 2: check appointment count exceed with the new record
 step 3: if not, save new appointment
 step 4: return count+1

}
```

If two or more threads(requests) enter into this transaction concurrently, there is a possibility to read incorrect appointment count. What is the best way to avoid this situation?

Thanks!

P.S: Serializable transaction isolation level might solve this problem. But since it restrict whole process to a single thread at a time, is it slow down the considerable performance in a large scale application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could increment the count in some other entity, and use optimistic locking on this other entity to have the transaction rolled back if another transaction tries to increment the count concurrently:

- step 1: read current appointments count from AppointmentStatistics entity (current appointments list size)
- step 2: check appointment count exceed with the new record
- step 3: if not, save new appointment and increment count of AppointmentStatistics
- step 4: return count+1

Hibernate will detect the change in the version field of the AppointmentStatistics entity if some other transaction has updated the count, and the transaction will rollback.

Comment: Each appointment related with a person registered in the db. So each person get separate appointments count. If i share this counting entity, two or more appointments made to different people will also get blocked. how to avoid that situation? thanks!

Comment: Add the count to the Person entity itself

Comment: your solution is great. can you tell me how to do detect that statistic entity has been changed concurrently by some other transaction?

Comment: and what if multiple JVM access this same code concurrently with a centralized db?

Comment: Optimistic locking will do that for you. When Hibernate updates the entity, if some other transaction (in whatever VM) has incremented the version field, then Hibernate will detect it and throw an exception.

Comment: ok. can we make next transaction wait until other finish without throwing an exception?

Comment: That would be pessimistic locking: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#transactions-locking. I'd rather use optimistic locking, with a retry strategy in case of an exception.

Comment: @Transactional(isolation=SERIALIZABLE) works as well for this situation. is it ok to use?

Comment: If your database supports it, then yes. But it will drsatically reduce your throughput if the method is called very often.